# Google Developer Console: failed to load DoubleClick Bid Manager API

Tags: google-api, console, bids, double-click-advertising

Anyone else having trouble adding the DoubleClick Bid Manager API to his/her Google Developer Console?
It's always showing "Failed to load" to me.

All other APIs can be added normally (especially the other Advertising APIs). So I am wondering what's wrong with the DoubleClick Bid Manager API.

Comment: did you remember to Enable billing?  https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/getting-started#access-cloud

Comment: Yes, billing is enabled. Used for bigquery, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Am seeing the same issue when trying to enable the DBM API for a cloud console project.

I have previously enabled the DBM API for a different cloud console project registered under an email address which is **also** authorised to access DBM.

I've just disabled and then successfully enabled the DBM API for this project and it worked fine. No 'failed to load' error. phew.

My suspicion based on this is that you can only enable the DBM API for projects registered under an email address which is authorised to access DBM.

I've sent feedback to Google on this and based on previous experience I don't expect to hear back anytime soon...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it just has come down to missing permissions for DBM. It took a long while for the DBM-"owner/admin" (here: agency) to figure out what permissions are missing.